# Selenium and Javascript, unable to locate firstchild element

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, cucumber

I'm new to Javascript and Selenium so please bear with me!

How would I locate the element 'Accept' and click it?

[image]

I have tried a few combinations:

```
var buttons =[];
buttons = driver.findElement(By.className("eula-button")) (I cannot call buttons.length with this method to loop through elements)
```

and

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'Accept')]")).click();
```

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Check if the buttons are inside an iframe.

Comment: Which error the second option with xpath gives you? It looks like correct one.

Answer (score 0):

Try using xpath something like this -

```
var button = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//button[@class='eula-button']"));
```

Comment: The button has two values for class. Your selector will not pick up the element.

Comment: ^that and there are two buttons in the screenshot that both have exactly the same classes so it won't be unique (but it is the first... at least that we can see).

Comment: Thanks for your help!  needed to add a driver.wait and then it worked!

Answer (score 0):

The xpath selector you used would work just fine.

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//button[contains(text(),'Accept')]")).click();
```

Alternatively you could use an index with CSS, presuming that the "Accept" button will always appear before "Decline".

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector(".eula-button-container button.eula-button:nth-of-type(1)")
```

Considering that your first selector with XPath isn't working, I would guess that the buttons are within an iframe, as pointed out in the comments by @Grasshopper.

Before interacting with the buttons, you will have to switch to the frame, then execute `findElement`

Comment: Thanks for your help!  You were right the xpath selector was fine.  I needed to add a driver.wait and then it worked!